# \Magento\Framework\Registry already exists in context object?

Tags: magento-2.1

I wrote the following code for displaying the products (like widget.)

```
    use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
    use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
    use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Module\Manager as ModuleManager;
    use Magento\Framework\Registry;
    use Faonni\ProductMostOrdered\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

    /**
       * Product Most Ordered Block
      */
       class ProductList extends AbstractProduct implements  IdentityInterface
     { 
        /**
          * Core Registry
          *
          * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
         */
        protected $_coreRegistry;

/**
 * Product Collection
 * 
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
 */
protected $_itemCollection;

/**
 * Catalog Product Visibility
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
 */
protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

/**
 * Module Manager
 * 
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
 */
protected $moduleManager;

/**
 * Reports Product Collection Factory
 * 
 * @var \Faonni\ProductMostOrdered\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_productsFactory;    

/**
 * Initialize Block
 *
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
 * @param ModuleManager $moduleManager
 * @param Registry $registry
 * @param CollectionFactory $productsFactory
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
    ModuleManager $moduleManager,
    Registry $registry,
    CollectionFactory $productsFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
    $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    $this->_productsFactory = $productsFactory;

    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
}
```

When I do bin/magento setup:di:compile it is showing error like

Incorrect dependency in class Faonni\ProductMostOrdered\Block\ProductList in /var/www/html/New/magento-dev/app/code/Faonni/ProductMostOrdered/Block/ProductList.php
\Magento\Framework\Registry already exists in the context object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the context registry should fix it :

$this->_coreRegistry = **$context->getRegistry();**

Meaning instead of injecting both your registry and context's registry you can use the context registry directly

so your code should be like :

```
<?php
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface; 
use Magento\Framework\Module\Manager as ModuleManager;
use Faonni\ProductMostOrdered\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
/**
  * Product Most Ordered Block
*/
class ProductList extends AbstractProduct implements IdentityInterface {

 /**
      * Core Registry
      *
      * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;    

/**
 * Product Collection
 * 
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
 */
protected $_itemCollection;

/**
 * Catalog Product Visibility
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
 */
protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

/**
 * Module Manager
 * 
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
 */
protected $moduleManager;

/**
 * Reports Product Collection Factory
 * 
 * @var \Faonni\ProductMostOrdered\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_productsFactory;

/**
 * Initialize Block
 *
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
 * @param ModuleManager $moduleManager
 * @param Registry $registry
 * @param CollectionFactory $productsFactory
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
        Context $context, 
        Visibility $catalogProductVisibility, 
        ModuleManager $moduleManager, 
        CollectionFactory $productsFactory, 
        array $data = []
) {
    $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
    $this->moduleManager             = $moduleManager;
    $this->_coreRegistry             = $context->getRegistry();
    $this->_productsFactory          = $productsFactory;

    parent::__construct(
            $context, $data
    );
}
//...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Registry $registry` from argument and

Replace below line

> $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;

to

> $this->_coreRegistry = $context->getRegistry();

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to include `Magento\Framework\Registry` again in your class as you are extending `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct` and it already includes `Magento\Framework\Registry`.
Removing `Magento\Framework\Registry` from your class will solve your issue.